# How to change autocompleter widget size

Tags: struts2-jquery-plugin

I tried the code from the project to change the size of the select box using [`<sj:autocompleter>`](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki/AutocompleterTag):

```xml
<strong>Result Div :</strong>
<div id="formResult" class="result ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">Submit form bellow.</div>
<strong>Topics Div :</strong>
<div id="topics" class="result ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></div>
<s:form id="form" action="echo" theme="simple" cssClass="yform">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Select Box as Autocompleter</legend>
        <div class="type-select">
            <label for="echo">Echo: </label>
            <sj:autocompleter
                    id="customers"
                    name="echo"
                    list="%{customers}"
                    listValue="name"
                    listKey="id"
                    selectBox="true"
                    selectBoxIcon="true"
                    onChangeTopics="autocompleteChange"
                    onFocusTopics="autocompleteFocus"
                    onSelectTopics="autocompleteSelect"
                    cssStyle="width:100%;"
                    />
        </div>
        <div>
            <sj:submit
                    targets="formResult"
                    value="AJAX Submit"
                    indicator="indicator"
                    button="true"
                    />
            <img id="indicator" src="images/indicator.gif" alt="Loading..." style="display:none"/>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</s:form>

<br/>
```

but it doesn't work. I don't know what is the problem with this code.

Comment: Don't think you can do it directly. But with css something like that will do the job `.type-select .s2j-combobox-input {width:500px;}`.

Comment: Does it work if you use `width:100% !important;` ? For debug purposes only, obviously. If it works, another rule is overriding your (and since it is inline style, the other is `!important` too). Class `type-select` should be useful too, along with the generated HTML.

Comment: `!important` is a bad hack that forces the CSS engine of the browser to reprocess all the rules for the target of your selector (in your case, your object, since you used inline-style) by setting that rule as the most important. It should not be used in production (but it often is) but is the fastest way (along with firebug) to see if your rule works but is being overriden by another one [with an higher specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/), or with `!important`, or if your rule is not working at all.

Comment: When you set a rule and it does not work (as your `width: 100%;`), it could be due to: 1) your rule is (syntactically or semantically) wrong, OR 2) your rule is right but it is overriden by another (from imported CSS files, `<style>` blocks, an so on). To be immediately sure you are not in case 2), you can set `!important` to your rule. Then you can start working on your rule. Otherwise, you can start searching the rule that is overriding your (because it has !important too, or because it has an higher specificity).

Comment: (Obviously Firebug's CSS box is enough when you are used to it and the number of overall rules is not too high)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at generated HTML neither `cssStyle` nor `cssClass` of `<sj:autocompleter>` tag is set to actual input field. But you can use plain CSS to style this input field. Put your `<sj:autocompleter>` inside of some element to change only specific input then you can use something like that:

```css
.type-select .s2j-combobox-input {
      width: 100%;
}
```

Where `type-select` is class of wrapper element and `s2j-combobox-input` is the class of generated input field for the `<sj:autocompleter>`.